# Heroku and Django: Couldn't find that process type (web)

Tags: django, heroku

I know this has been asked a lot of times but none of the solutions seem to work. I am trying to run a Django app in Heroku but am running into issues when I try to scale dynos.

```
➜  main-website git:(master) heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

The issue seems to be related to `ProcFile`. This is what I have configured in my root directory (same as `requirements.txt` etc).

`web: gunicorn main-website.wsgi:application --log-file -`

What am I missing or doing wrong so I can correct this?

Project Structure

```
➜  main-website git:(master) tree -L 3
.
├── app
│   ├── about
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── contact
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── home
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── static
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── privacy
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── app
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── images
│   │   └── scripts
│   └── templates
│       ├── about.html
│       ├── contact.html
│       ├── footer.html
│       ├── header.html
│       ├── home.html
│       ├── layout.html
│       ├── privacy.html
│       └── slider.html
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── ProcFile
└── requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name is `Procfile` not `ProcFile`.

Then try this `web: gunicorn main-website.wsgi:application --log-file -`